# Python csv compare two file, update value if two value is matched

Tags: python

After reviewed few recommend similar topic about comparing value, there is not much help for me.

car.csv

```
tittle1,tittle2
bmw,2000
mercedes,2000
toyota,1000
honda,1500
geely,500
```

price.csv

```
ori_price1,new_price2
2000,5000
1000,2500
```

The result should looks like
tittle1,tittle2

```
bmw,5000
mercedes,5000
toyota,2500
honda,1500
geely,500
```

I have found the code below is very close to the result

```
import csv

    with open('car.csv', 'r') as csv_file, open('price.csv', 'r', newline='') as csv_file2 \
            ,open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        csv_reader2 = csv.DictReader(csv_file2)
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

        csv_writer.writerow([ 'tittle1', 'title2'])

        for row1,row2 in zip(csv_reader,csv_reader2):
          csv_writer.writerow([row1['tittle1'],row1['tittle2'],row2['new_price2']])
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use vlookup at excel?

Comment: Is it a pandas library?

Comment: I think he meant to ask why not do this directly in Excel. Is there a specific reason you want to do this in python and, from the looks of it, you're interested in using the pandas library?

Comment: @kerwei I see, I do this data mapping for practice my python skill. The pandas library looks interesting but seems too advanced for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `pandas`, it can be rather simple:

```
import pandas as pd

cars=pd.read_csv("./cars.csv")
prices=pd.read_csv("./price.csv")

### iterate over the price changes as rows
for i,row in prices.iterrows(): 
    ### find where cars["tittle2"]==row["ori_price1"]
    #   and update column ['tittle2'] to row["new_price2"]
    cars.loc[cars["tittle2"]==row["ori_price1"], ['tittle2']] = row["new_price2"]

cars.to_csv("cars_updated.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Awesome, pandas are short and clean.